# Detect if screensaver, configured by GPO, is running on remote PC

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, screensaver, gpo

I am trying to detect if screen saver is running on a remote PC using WMI. The remote PC is Windows 7, but it should work for W8/W10 as well.

So far I was testing having screen saver set manually on the remote PC (via control panel) and relying on WMI `Win32_Process` containing *SCREEN_SAVER_NAME.SCR*:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = "Username";
options.Password = "password";

ManagementScope scope =
    new ManagementScope(
    "\\\\10.1.1.1\\root\\cimv2", options);
 scope.Connect();

while (true)
{
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

    foreach (var item in queryCollection)
    {
        if ((string)item["Description"] == "PhotoScreensaver.scr")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("screensaver running");
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine when the screen saver is set via control panel on the remote PC.

However, when setting the screen saver via group policy, WMI `Win32_Process` no longer lists the .SCR file and my software obviously doesn't work as expected.

Any idea how to detect running screen savers, which was set using GPO?

Comment: Bob, have you inspected `queryCollection` already? Maybe you just need to look for an other name/description...

Comment: I used WMIEXPLORER to go through all processes and couldn't find anything relevant unfortunately.

Comment: Can it be that the screensaver process is running as an other user in case of GPO? Maybe it's a matter of giving the correct rights to the user that you use for the WMI query?

Comment: My user has administrator rights, so that should not be a problem. But it's a good question how GPO is actually running it. I was trying to google that, but couldn't find any details.

Comment: Do you recall how you solved this, if you did? I'm about to write a quick-and-dirty user inactivity monitor, and I'd like to base it on the GPO-configured screen saver process.

Comment: @InteXX Unfortunately I did not resolve this. Please let me know if you find a way to do it. Cheers.

Comment: Actually, since posting I've come up with a way to neatly sidestep the problem. I've determined to build a custom screen saver that includes a WCF client; I'll then use [PsExec](http://serverfault.com/a/509569/218519) to deploy/update it on all workstations. What's your situation? Could this work for you as well?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not helpful in my case. I am not allowed to upload any type of agent to any of the workstations. Thanks for sharing though.

Comment: Update: I've realized that the screen saver idea won't work for my situation. I believe I've come up with an alternative, though, that may solve both our problems. What's your requirement? (Note: for this comment thread, make sure to preface your replies with @InteXX, so that I receive them.)

Comment: @InteXX My requirements are simple: detect if screen saver is working using LAN. No agents, nor special screen savers allowed. This is to be used in different environments (with W7-W10), where I am not able to control what is on PCs or upload agents etc. so another words we know that client computers are Windows 7-to-10 and that is all we have.

Comment: ...and then *that* idea didn't work. I was experimenting with PsExec to upload (using the handy -c switch) and run a small .EXE to PInvoke a call to `GetLastInputInfo()`. But it turned out that the call only returns inactivity info for the current session—I needed it for all sessions. Also, we have a few laptops that leave the building from time to time; a server call would never reach them. So in the end I've settled on a WinForms tray app that reports back to a WCF service. But... back to your situation. Have you looked at PsList or PsExec -c? Could either of those help?

Comment: What is your purpose? For what reason do you need to check for a screen saver process on these remote computers? It sounds like they're subject to your GPO, so you've got an enormous advantage there right at the start.

Comment: We'd better not use up this thread space for this conversation. Email me through my website.